# Replace deprecated `this.$()` in Ember 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

`this.$()` [has been deprecated](https://deprecations.emberjs.com/v3.x/#toc_jquery-apis) in Ember.js and will be removed in Ember 4. It should be replaced with native Javascript. Still, the migration could be hard to do in one shot.

Is this the right way to replace previous `this.$()` while continuing using JQuery?

```js
// BEFORE
this.$().on('transitionend', () => this.doSomething());

// AFTER
import $ from 'jquery';

$(this.element).on('transitionend', () => this.doSomething());
```

Or is there another approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This would be a valid step even so it's a very small one. I would recommend that you try to replace jQuery with native JavaScript at least for the easy targets. There is even a codemod to help you doing so:

```
npx ember-3x-codemods jquery-apis path/of/files/
```

Please find more Infos in [it's documentation](https://github.com/ember-codemods/ember-3x-codemods/blob/master/transforms/jquery-apis/README.md).

Comment: That codemod is dangerous. It treats every jQuery method as if it were a call to an event handler method. Any one who reads this should avoid it, unless the only use of jQuery in their Ember project is just event handling.